# Can I view daily vote breakdown between questions and answers?

Tags: support, voting

I know that the number of votes I get per day depends on the ratio of answer votes to question votes to encourage people to vote on both.  Currently, I have 12 votes today, but short of tracking the breakdown myself of how I have voted, how do I determine how many of those are question votes and how many are answer votes.  I know how to get this breakdown for my whole history on SO but not how to get this for the day

Comment: this used to be displayed in your profile at some point... can't find it now.